# MongoDB aggregation: flatten array property into root array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm working on a feature that recursively looks up a thread of comments using `$graphLookUp`, and I almost have it. (albeit in a somewhat convoluted way but it is working!)

The last step I need is the following:
***instead of having the nested `posteriorThread` as a property of the root array (`$$ROOT`), just merge it onto the root itself.***

- AGGREGATION CODE:

```
const posteriorThread = await Comment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: post.threadDescendant
    }
  },

  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: 'baseposts',
      startWith: '$threadDescendant',
      connectFromField: 'threadDescendant',
      connectToField: '_id',
      as: 'posteriorThread'
    }
  },

  {
    $unwind: '$posteriorThread'
  },

  {
    $sort: { 'posteriorThread.depth': 1 }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      posteriorThread: { $push: '$posteriorThread' },
      root: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      'root.posteriorThread': 0
    }
  },

  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            posteriorThread: '$posteriorThread'
          },
          '$root'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

- CURRENT OUTPUT

```
 OUTPUT: posteriorThread
[
  {
    _id: '5f7eab40575e6fc56ee07604',
    onModel: 'BasePost',
    depth: 1,
    user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
    text: 'thread 0',
    isThread: true,
    threadDescendant: '5f7eabad575e6fc56ee07607',
    posteriorThread: [
      {
        _id: '5f7eabad575e6fc56ee07607',
        onModel: 'Comment',
        depth: 2,
        user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
        text: 'thread 1',
        isThread: true,
        threadDescendant: '5f7eac82575e6fc56ee07609'
      },
      {
        _id: '5f7eac82575e6fc56ee07609',
        onModel: 'Comment',
        depth: 3,
        user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
        text: 'thread 2',
        isThread: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

- DESIRED OUTPUT

```
OUTPUT: posteriorThread 
[
  {
    _id: '5f7eab40575e6fc56ee07604',
    onModel: 'BasePost',
    depth: 1,
    user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
    text: 'thread 0',
    isThread: true,
    threadDescendant: '5f7eabad575e6fc56ee07607'
  },
  {
    _id: '5f7eabad575e6fc56ee07607',
    onModel: 'Comment',
    depth: 2,
    user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
    text: 'thread 1',
    isThread: true,
    threadDescendant: '5f7eac82575e6fc56ee07609'
  },
  {
    _id: '5f7eac82575e6fc56ee07609',
    onModel: 'Comment',
    depth: 3,
    user: '5f5da45245c07cc06e51b09f',
    text: 'thread 2',
    isThread: true
  }
];
```

I could accomplish this after the aggregation in regular js, but I would prefer to do it all in the aggregation.
The part that needs to be replaced is the `mergeObjects` bit and replaced with something else or the `group` aggregation and taking a different strategy, but I'm not sure what to put in it's place.
Also, if you have any other suggestions to make this cleaner, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Sunil K Samanta for steering me in the right direction. It's not the prettiest solution, but it does give me the right solution.

```
const posteriorThread = await Comment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: post.threadDescendant
    }
  },

  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: 'baseposts',
      startWith: '$threadDescendant',
      connectFromField: 'threadDescendant',
      connectToField: '_id',
      as: 'posteriorThread'
    }
  },

  {
    $unwind: '$posteriorThread'
  },

  {
    $sort: { 'posteriorThread.depth': 1 }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      items: { $push: '$$ROOT.posteriorThread' },
      root: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
    },
  },

  {
    $project: {
      items: 1,
      root: { $slice: ['$$ROOT.root', 0, 1] },
    },
  },

  {
    $project: {
      'root.posteriorThread': 0,
    },
  },

  {
    $addFields: {
      allItems: {
        $concatArrays: ['$root', '$items'],
      },
    },
  },

  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        full_posterior: '$$ROOT.allItems',
      },
    },
  },
])
)[0].full_posterior;
```

Comment: `[0].full_posterior` is what we are trying to avoid in the first place

Answer (score 6):

Its really challenging. Atleast for me. And really very interesting case. Lets try my solution. Hope it works..

```
db.test.aggregate([

    // PREVIOSU STEPS YOU ALREADY DID

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            items: {$push: "$$ROOT"},
            subItems: {$first: "$posteriorThread"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "items.posteriorThread": 0
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            allItems: {
                $concatArrays: ["$items", "$subItems"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            mergedItems: {$push: "$allItems"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$mergedItems"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$mergedItems"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: "$mergedItems"
        }
    }

])
```

Comment: Hey, your solution did not work because subItems is not an array and therefore could not be concatenated, but it did get me closer! I basically have it now, but the `$replaceRoot` is still leaving me with an nested array, but it's not a big deal as I can just get the correct solution after the aggregation.

Comment: Check out my answer if you want to see my final solution.

Comment: Nice to hear that you got your solution. 
I don't know why my solution didn't work. I actually worked on your CURRENT OUTPUT. 
That means you have to use your steps you already did and then add my pipeline stages after your existing stages. 
In your CURRENT OUTPUT the posteriorThread is an array of items. So it sould have worked. anyway I actually stored your CURRENT OUTPUT into a collection and then I tried my steps. It gave me the results. Anyway the problem was really interesting..

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Yeah, subItems is using $first which returns an object, so when I went to $concat it was throwing and error, something like 'Cannot concat and object'. But yeah, I thought adding a simple thread feature would be a few lines and it turned into a whole day endeavor of aggregation and bugs! Thanks again for your help; it really set me on the right path. If you want to copy and paste my answer, I'll give you the credit for the answer.

Comment: Haha.. No no. Not needed. Please. I'm glad it really helped! And thank you for asking. And honestly I had no idea how I'd do that, it was experimental for me too. The problem statement was interesting. So I started working on that and I also got some lessons from it.